Typing error when receiving a property of type Date and returning it to the API in type string
I currently have a service listing screen in reactjs that renders two modals with different triggers. I had asked a previous question here on the platform, but someone else helped me solve it. You can take a look at this link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78425045/modal-doesnt-close-on-submission/78425265?noredirect=1#comment138283654_78425265]
I used the solution for a large part of my code, but when I went to use the same logic in this part of my code, I had a typing problem when passing the "form" prop to my new service modal:
import { Book, BookOpenCheck } from 'lucide-react'

import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button'
import { Dialog, DialogTrigger } from '@/components/ui/dialog'

import { NewAttendance } from './modals/new-attendance'
import { useNewAttendanceController } from './modals/new-attendance/use-new-attendance-controller'
import { NewMedicalRecords } from './modals/new-medical-records'
import { useNewMedicalRecords } from './modals/new-medical-records/use-new-medical-records-controller'

export function ListOfServices() {
  const {
    form: formNewMedicalRecords,
    onSubmit: onSubmitNewMedicalRecords,
    isPending: isPendingNewMedicalRecords,
    isNewMedicalRecords,
    setIsNewMedicalRecords,
  } = useNewMedicalRecords()

  const {
    form: formNewAttendance,
    onSubmit: onSubmitNewAttendance,
    isPending: isPendingNewAttendance,
    isNewAttendanceModalOpen,
    setIsNewAttendanceModalOpen,
  } = useNewAttendanceController()

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
      <div className="flex items-center gap-3 w-full">
        <Dialog
          open={isNewMedicalRecords}
          onOpenChange={setIsNewMedicalRecords}
        >
          <DialogTrigger asChild>
            <Button variant="outline" size="xs">
              <span>Registrar Prontuário</span>
              <BookOpenCheck className="ml-2 w-4 h-4" />
            </Button>
          </DialogTrigger>

          <NewMedicalRecords
            form={formNewMedicalRecords}
            onSubmit={onSubmitNewMedicalRecords}
            isPending={isPendingNewMedicalRecords}
          />
        </Dialog>

        <Dialog
          open={isNewAttendanceModalOpen}
          onOpenChange={setIsNewAttendanceModalOpen}
        >
          <DialogTrigger asChild>
            <Button variant="outline" size="xs">
              <span>Registrar Atendimento</span>
              <Book className="ml-2 w-4 h-4" />
            </Button>
          </DialogTrigger>

          <NewAttendance
            form={formNewAttendance}
            onSubmit={onSubmitNewAttendance}
            isPending={isPendingNewAttendance}
          />
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

I'm using the z.input and z.output methods in zod, because initially I have a property that receives a Date and returns it to the API as a string. This is my schema and all the logic of my new service controller:
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod'
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from '@tanstack/react-query'
import { addDays } from 'date-fns'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import toast from 'react-hot-toast'
import { z } from 'zod'

import attendanceService from '@/services/attendanceService'

export const newAttendanceSchema = z.object({
  clientHashId: z.string({ required_error: 'ID do Cliente é obrigatório' }),
  employeeHashId: z.string({
    required_error: 'ID do Funcionário é obrigatório',
  }),
  serviceDate: z
    .date()
    .transform((date) => new Intl.DateTimeFormat().format(date)),
  serviceHour: z.string().transform((time) => time.concat(':00')),
})

export type NewAttendanceOutputSchema = z.output<typeof newAttendanceSchema>
export type NewAttendanceInputSchema = z.input<typeof newAttendanceSchema>

export function useNewAttendanceController() {
  const [isNewAttendanceModalOpen, setIsNewAttendanceModalOpen] =
    useState(false)

  const openNewAttendanceModal = () => {
    setIsNewAttendanceModalOpen(true)
  }

  const closeNewAttendanceModal = () => {
    setIsNewAttendanceModalOpen(false)
  }

  const queryClient = useQueryClient()

  const { mutateAsync, isPending } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: attendanceService.registerService,
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: ['get-attendances'],
      })
    },
  })

  const form = useForm<
    NewAttendanceInputSchema,
    null,
    NewAttendanceOutputSchema
  >({
    resolver: zodResolver(newAttendanceSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      clientHashId: '',
      employeeHashId: '',
      serviceDate: addDays(new Date(), 1),
      serviceHour: '',
    },
  })

  async function onSubmit(data: NewAttendanceOutputSchema) {
    try {
      await mutateAsync({
        clientHashId: data.clientHashId,
        employeeHashId: data.employeeHashId,
        serviceDate: data.serviceDate,
        serviceHour: data.serviceHour,
      })

      toast.success('Agendamento cadastrado com sucesso!')
      closeNewAttendanceModal()
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error('Erro ao enviar a requisição')
      form.reset({
        clientHashId: '',
        employeeHashId: '',
        serviceDate: addDays(new Date(), 1),
        serviceHour: '',
      })
    }
  }

  return {
    form,
    onSubmit,
    isPending,
    isNewAttendanceModalOpen,
    setIsNewAttendanceModalOpen,
    openNewAttendanceModal,
    closeNewAttendanceModal,
  }
}

The error I get is when I give the "form" property to my  component:
The type 'UseFormReturn<{ clientHashId: string; employeeHashId: string; serviceDate: Date; serviceHour: string; }, null, { clientHashId: string; employeeHashId: string; serviceDate: string; serviceHour: string; }>' cannot be assigned to the type 'UseFormReturn<{ clientHashId: string; employeeHashId: string; serviceDate: string; serviceHour: string; }>'.
The types returned by 'watch()' are incompatible between these types.
The type '{ clientHashId: string; employeeHashId: string; serviceDate: Date; serviceHour: string; }' cannot be assigned to the type '{ clientHashId: string; employeeHashId: string; serviceDate: string; serviceHour: string; }'.

